# Check a string if it only contains letters from the alphabet and not numbers or other stuff in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I have a question. I'm researched it on the web and of course with the search function here on stackoverflow. I also found a few similiar question but they where either in another programming language or not exactly I want to do. 
**So here is my question in detail:**

I'm creating a simple console Hangman game (im a beginner). I'm doing this just on my own because I think I learn the most if I do it on my own. Anyway I ask the user for his word and save it into a variable. I also make it Uppercase. 
Now I want to check if this word only contains valid letters from the alphabet. 
Than I want to put this in a if condition so he will be ask again if he enters for example a number.

But I have no idea how to do this? I tried it with the tryparse method and contains but I can't come to a solution. So I'm asking you kindly how to do this?

My code:

```
class Hangman
{
    private string enteredWord;
    private char guessedLetter;



    public void Start()
    {
        enteredWord = AskUserForWord();
        Console.WriteLine(enteredWord);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private string AskUserForWord()
    {



        Console.WriteLine("Bitte gib ein Wort ein das es zu erraten gilt. Sag deinem Mitspieler er soll weg sehen: ");
        string word = ToUpper(Console.ReadLine());

        if ()
        return word;
    }


    private string ToUpper(string word)
    {

        return word.ToUpper();

    }

}
```

Comment: I think this should work `word.All(c => char.IsLetter(c))`

Comment: I notice the German message. Do you realise that the German alphabet is not the same as the English alphabet, with many people assuming by an unqualified "alphabet" that you want the English one? Do you want all characters from the German alphabet to be accepted, or perhaps even another alphabet?

Comment: You're one lucky guy who has been advised by 7 different people with essentially the same solution! :)

Comment: Thank you for the great help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job :

```
bool result = input.All(Char.IsLetter);
```

and also a regex solution :

```
Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"^[\p{L}]+$");
```

The Char.IsLetter is the better solution since it counts as a letter any language alphabets. This regex will also count them but still it looks more compact with IsLetter

Comment: Hi thanks the input.All() is the perfect solution for me. I implemented it and it works just fine :)

Comment: Glad it helped feel free to mark it as an answer so you let know the other viewers that this helped you out

Answer (score 1):

First reference system.linq:

```
using System.Linq;
```

then modify your `AskUserForWord()` function:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bitte gib ein Wort ein das es zu erraten gilt. Sag deinem Mitspieler er soll weg sehen: ");
   string word = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

   if (word.All(c => char.IsLetter(c))
       return word;

   Console.WriteLine("Also bitte, nur Buchstaben sind hier erlaubt!");
}
```

Comment: Hi,
thank you for this solution.
I have it now as followed: 

    private string AskUserForWord()
        {

            while (true)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bitte gib ein Wort ein das es zu erraten gilt. Sag deinem Mitspieler er soll weg sehen: ");
                string word = ToUpper(Console.ReadLine());

                bool result = word.All(Char.IsLetter);

                if (result)
                {
                    return word;
                }
            }

But I don't understand your solution. Why `` if (word.All(c => char.IsLetter(c)) `` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions.

For alphabets,

```
Regex.IsMatch(word, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be checked with this.

```
bool isLettersOnly = !word.Any(c => !char.IsLetter(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

read up on Regex aka Regular expressions, they are good for describing exactly how you want your input to be, in your case it would be something like:

```
Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]*");
```

this means only accept strings which consist of alphabetic characters.

look at this example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4(v=vs.110).aspx to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try with a Regular expression.

```
Match match = Regex.Match("Testing a valid input ", @"(?i)^[a-z]+");

            if (match.Success)
            {
                //validation passed
            }
```